# Can I set multiple columns to NULL in MySQL in bulk?

Tags: mysql, null, sql-update, bulkupdate

I have a very large database and for testing, I want to set a certain amount of data to NULL.

As an example, I have 57 columns across 3 tables, all of which need to be nullified. I can't delete the rows, I just need to know that if the row exists and there's no data in those fields, that everything still works.

To clarify, all the data in those fields has been moved to anther table, and the old data was not wiped in the migration. To test my reports I need to know that the reports are pulling from the new location, not the old, since as new data is added, it will only go to the new location. Our plan is to generate each report from the old database, migrate, and then generate them again and compare. But to ensure that they are pulling from the right place, we want to wipe the old data so it doesn't provide a false positive.

Is there a way for me to do this in bulk or should I resign myself to writing one comma separated SET statement after another?

Comment: I don't get it... do you want EVERY field of EVERY table to be null of there will be a predeterminated set that will be saved (such as ID)? Or maybe are you asking how to do an update without specifying the field names (something that sounds like "*set null to every column that is not this one*") ?

Comment: There is a predetermined set that will be saved (ID among them), so "every column except XY&Z" would be great, as would "set all these () to null" rather than "set this one to null and this one to null and this one to null"

Comment: How many columns that need to be set to NULL are we talking about?

Comment: The biggest table has 37, one has 29, one has 22, one has 9 (that's one where I have to keep some of the data, I can't just truncate and recreate the rows), and 8 tables have between 1 and 3

Comment: So is the question about writing 12 UPDATE statements with overall like 100 columns, which you want to set to NULL?

Comment: Exactly. I was just wondering if there was an easier way. Originally I thought there would be more, but it turns out the longest part of the project was figuring out which tables (out of over 200) and which columns. It sounds like there isn't an easier way for the update itself, and since I don't have to update columns in all 200 tables I just used a lot of copy-paste and got it done.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the statements using the data from the internal `information_schema.COLUMNS` table.

Assuming you have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  keep1 INT,
  keep2 INT,
  set_null1 INT,
  set_null2 INT,
  set_null3 INT
);
```

and you want to set all columns to NULL except of `keep1` and `keep2`. Execute the following script:

```
set @db_name = 'test';
set @table_name = 'my_table';
set @exclude_columns = 'keep1,keep2';

select concat(
  'UPDATE `', @table_name, '` SET\n',
  group_concat('`', COLUMN_NAME, '` = NULL' separator ',\n'),
  ';'
)
from information_schema.COLUMNS c
where c.TABLE_SCHEMA = @db_name
  and c.TABLE_NAME   = @table_name
  and find_in_set(c.COLUMN_NAME, @exclude_columns) = 0;
```

This will generate the following statement:

```
UPDATE `my_table` SET
`set_null1` = NULL,
`set_null2` = NULL,
`set_null3` = NULL;
```

Copy the result and paste it into your UPDATE script. Do it for all 12 tables adjusting the variables `@db_name`, `@table_name` and `@exclude_columns`.

See demo on [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7EtG5gHYffEjpNS7sL4FFe/0).

Answer (score 0):

This is a very unusual task for an SQL database, so it's not surprising that it's a bit awkward.

As you know, to set multiple columns to NULL in an UPDATE statement, you'd have to set each column individually.

```
UPDATE mytable
SET col1 = NULL, col2 = NULL, ... col57 = NULL
WHERE id = ?;
```

That could be quite a bit of typing.  Or it could be a task to write code to loop over the column names in your table, and concatenate the terms for UPDATE statement. Up to you.

An alternative that might be easier is to delete the row and then re-insert it with no values specified except the primary key.

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE id = ?;
INSERT INTO mytable SET id = ?;
```

By omitting the other columns, they'll be NULL or else take a DEFAULT value defined in your table. If you want those columns with defaults to be NULL too, you'll have to specify that.

```
INSERT INTO mytable SET id = ?, col23 = NULL;
```

Comment: Yeah, this is a good idea. In some cases I was hoping to save more than just the id, but it might be easier to drop and recreate. If there are tables where the id is really the only thing I want to save, I can probably just truncate the whole thing and insert the right number of rows.